# Stripe checkout button does not do anything on mobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe payment in my ASP.NET MVC app. The checkout button works on desktop and redirects user to Stripe checkout page, but the button doesn't do anything on mobile.
I tried Edge and Chrome on iOS and both are not working.

This is my JavaScript in razor page (Cart.cshtml)

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" id="stripe-checkout-button" value="Stripe" />
    }    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('MyStripePublishKey');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('stripe-checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fetch('https://mywebsite.com/Cart/Checkout_Stripe', {
                method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                window.location.href = "/Cart/GatewayRedirectFailed";
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

The button does submit the form and there is no error. Also I have to mention, the client-side validation happens, because I have a agreement checkbox which is tagged as "required", and there is a pop-over for that checkbox, pressing the button only triggers that validation.

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Is the alert in your error condition triggering? Try setting up mobile browser debugging (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) and see what code path is being hit, what is logged in the browser console, are any exceptions or errors being thrown?

Comment: No. there is no error. I'll edit my question

Comment: is the button registering clicks? e.g. add a console log inside the button click handler and see if that is being run. And if the `stripe.redirectToCheckout()` part is being run or not

Comment: it could just be that your code isn't parsing out the response from your server, so worth looking into that fetch request and the response too

Comment: Good point! I verified the url "https://mywebsite.com/Cart/Checkout_Stripe" is fetched but looks like somehow the redirect does not happen and also I don't get any client-side or serve-side error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from Stripe support, they found I can make it work by updating my JavaScript as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('MyStripePublishKey');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('stripe-checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) { -- adding event parameter

        event.preventDefault();  <<-- this is the key to make it work!

        fetch('https://mywebsite.com/Cart/Checkout_Stripe', {
                method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                window.location.href = "/Cart/GatewayRedirectFailed";
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Because my form does not have any `action`, looks like in iPhone browser it's not working.